# Socket.IO send() not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a weird issue. I'm writing a simple Socket.IO echo server as a test, but I can't get the send() method to work. On the server I'm using this piece of code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000); 
var clients = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {     
        socket.send('test');

        socket.on('addclient', function(id) {
            socket.id = id;
            clients[id] = socket;
            console.log('New client connected: '+ id);
        });

        socket.on('echomessage', function(message) {
            console.log('Sending echo message to client '+ socket.id);
            socket.send(message);
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('Client '+ socket.id + ' disconnected');
            delete clients[socket.id];
        });
});
```

The send('test') is working perfectly, but when I emit the echomessage event, I don't receive the message. No error messages at all on the server or client side.

So, on the clientside I do this:

```
// Connect with the server (works, connection established)

// works too, I see it on the server
sock.emit('addclient', 1); 

// I see 'Sending echo message to client 1' on the server
sock.emit('echomessage', 'Echo this please');
```

But I don't receive the message at all.

I have absolutely no clue of what I'm doing wrong. All help is appreciated!

Comment: check if he client is connected to web socket he could just discard the msg.

Comment: what code on the client handles the server's message sent?

Comment: I'm using a Java implementation on the clientside. The client is connected, because I never get a 'connection terminated' message on either the client or the serverside. It just seems that the socket.send(message); piece doesn't work when the echomessage event is emitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is somewhere here :

```
    socket.on('addclient', function(id) {
        socket.id = id; // <-- 
        clients[id] = socket;
        console.log('New client connected: '+ id);
    });
```

Don't change `socket.id`, because it is an internal, and you might ruin the internal process of using a socket.

It is defined by socket.io itself : [source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.js#L39)

Comment: Great! That was indeed the issue.